# PHP Convert array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a permission system where I have to convert a single level array (separated by underscores) to a multidimentional array. Any help with a function that fix this?

Input array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dashboard
    [1] => dashboard_read
    [2] => dashboard_update
    [3] => dashboard_create
    [4] => dashboard_delete
    [5] => dashboard_search
    [6] => timeplan_event_read
    [7] => timeplan_event_search
    [8] => timeplan_read
    [9] => timeplan_search
    [10] => webhotel
    [11] => webhotel_read
    [12] => webhotel_update
    [13] => webhotel_create
    [14] => webhotel_delete
    [15] => webhotel_search
)
```

Output array:

```
array(
    'dashboard' => array(
        'read',
        'update',
        'create',
        'delete',
        'search'
    ),
    'timeplan' =>array(
        'read',
        'search',
        'event' => array(
            'read',
            'search'
        )
    ),
    'webhotel' =>array(
        'read',
        'update',
        'create',
        'delete',
        'search'
    ),
)
```

Comment: I think you should go with a `foreach` loop and `explode('_', ...)`.

Comment: I would recommend you come up with a more uniform structure. Currently it's hard to predict whether a given permission is an array key with more sub-keys or a value. That'll make it a pain to work with. Something like `['name' => .., 'children' => [..]]` would simplify that. Some classes could help here as well.

Comment: As hint for the future, its pretty nice if you can provide your input data as copy-able sourcecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $array = array("dashboard","dashboard_read","dashboard_update","dashboard_create","dashboard_delete","dashboard_search","timeplan_event_read","timeplan_event_search","timeplan_read","timeplan_search","webhotel","webhotel_read","webhotel_update","webhotel_create","webhotel_delete","webhotel_search");


 function build_arr($array, $delim='_') 
 { 
   $output = array();
   foreach($array as $key)
   {
    $main = explode($delim, $key);
    if (count($main) < 2)
        continue;

        $bottom = &$output;
        while(count($main) > 1) 
        {
                $sub = array_shift($main);
                if (!isset($bottom[$sub]))
                {
                    $bottom[$sub]  =  array();
                }
                    $bottom = &$bottom[$sub];
        }
                $bottom[] = $main[count($main)-1];
    }
    return $output;
 }

    // Input
    print_r( $array);

    // Output
    print_r( build_arr($array) );


 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 Array
 (
     [0] => dashboard
     [1] => dashboard_read
     [2] => dashboard_update
     [3] => dashboard_create
     [4] => dashboard_delete
     [5] => dashboard_search
     [6] => timeplan_event_read
     [7] => timeplan_event_search
     [8] => timeplan_read
     [9] => timeplan_search
     [10] => webhotel
     [11] => webhotel_read
     [12] => webhotel_update
     [13] => webhotel_create
     [14] => webhotel_delete
     [15] => webhotel_search
 )

 Array
 (
     [dashboard] => Array
         (
             [0] => read
             [1] => update
             [2] => create
             [3] => delete
             [4] => search
         )

     [timeplan] => Array
         (
             [event] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => read
                     [1] => search
                 )

             [0] => read
             [1] => search
         )

     [webhotel] => Array
         (
             [0] => read
             [1] => update
             [2] => create
             [3] => delete
             [4] => search
         )

 )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through your array and explode on '_'-character. After this you can simple build up your new array in your desired treeformat.

```
<?php
$tmp = array("dashboard","dashboard_read","dashboard_update","dashboard_create","dashboard_delete","dashboard_search","timeplan_event_read","timeplan_event_search","timeplan_read","timeplan_search","webhotel","webhotel_read","webhotel_update","webhotel_create","webhotel_delete","webhotel_search");

$newarray = array();

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    $parts = explode("_", $value);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
        continue;
    $arr = &$newarray;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($parts)-1;$i++) {
        if (!array_key_exists($parts[$i], $arr)) {
            $arr[$parts[$i]] = array();
        }
        $arr = &$arr[$parts[$i]];
    }
    $arr[] = $parts[count($parts)-1];
}

print_r($newarray);
```

--- Output ---

```
$ php -f tmp.php
Array
(
    [dashboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => read
            [1] => update
            [2] => create
            [3] => delete
            [4] => search
        )

    [timeplan] => Array
        (
            [event] => Array
                (
                    [0] => read
                    [1] => search
                )

            [0] => read
            [1] => search
        )

    [webhotel] => Array
        (
            [0] => read
            [1] => update
            [2] => create
            [3] => delete
            [4] => search
        )

)
```

Comment: It's create extra element `[timeplan] => Array([0] => event)` when trying on original data.

Comment: Thank you for down-vote, but when I test it with the input data from the op it works like a charm. No Problem.

Comment: It works with given input sample, if your original data is different from current one, that is your issue, not the one he answered, well done [take](http://stackoverflow.com/users/904665/take)

Comment: I'm sorry. I did recheck your code again and it works ok, so I undo my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I'd had the same problem times ago, but I don't know how the code exactly looks like. My idea was to write a recursive function, which `explode('_', $string)` the current permission, and iterates through the parts. And there it will do something like

```
if count $parts === 1:
   $result[] = $parts
else:
   $result[$parts[0]] = recursive call ($parts, $result)
```

I hope that this will bring you on the right way...

Answer (score 0):

No depth limit.

```
$arr = [];

while($path = array_pop($x))
{
    $parts = explode('_',$path);
    $value = array_pop($parts);
    $cell = &$arr;
    while($part = array_shift($parts)){
        if (!isset($cell[$part])) $cell[$part] = [];
        $cell = &$cell[$part];
    }
    if (!array_key_exists($value, $cell))
        array_push($cell, $value);
}
```

Output:

```
array:3 [
  "webhotel" => array:5 [
    0 => "search"
    1 => "delete"
    2 => "create"
    3 => "update"
    4 => "read"
  ]
  "timeplan" => array:3 [
    0 => "search"
    1 => "read"
    "event" => array:2 [
      0 => "search"
      1 => "read"
    ]
  ]
  "dashboard" => array:5 [
    0 => "search"
    1 => "delete"
    2 => "create"
    3 => "update"
    4 => "read"
  ]
]
```